# What is the proper capacitance for wetting current of switch

Tags: capacitance, charging

I have to use the OMRON V-161-1A5.
(Limit switch)
It has 16A for 250Vac specification.
But, I have to use it as a mirco load(0.1mA 24vdc)
I'm concerning the corrosion of contact.

So, I'm thinking of using the capacitor charging current when closing the N.O. contact for wetting current.
OMRON recommed over 5vdc 160mA.

What is the proper capacitance for wetting current?

Minimum voltage is 24vdc
Maximum is 220vdc.

Cencept drawing
[image: concept drawing]

Drawing below is full version

[image: new version]

Comment: A capacitor is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Please provide a circuit diagram showing how you intend to used the capacitor. Inparallel with the load I suspect?

Comment: I attached the concept drawing.

Comment: @AhnJInHo - Hi, FYI an OP (original poster) *must not* add new info & ask questions as an "answer" here on SE. It breaks the whole Q&A approach and may cause future problems for you, when such posts get deleted. In future, to add more images in a comment, the technique explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/310525) should be used. Note that the draft answer (or question) *must not be submitted*. It is used only to upload the image and is then discarded. If you need more help with this, please ask on our [meta]. Thanks. (I have copied your "answer" into comments on both answers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a resistor \$R_{1}\$ in series with \$C_{1}\$. The value of the resistor is:
$$R_{1}<\frac{24}{0.16}$$.

The capacitor is selected based on the bounce time of the switch. Make it large enough so that it will not charge up before the switch finishes de-bouncing and full wetting occurs.
$$R_{1}C_{1}>>t_{\text{bounce}}$$

Don't make it too large. The capacitor must be discharged between limit switch engagement intervals. You may need a discharging resistor across the capacitor to quickly discharge it because the load current is so small. Choose it so that at 250V the current passing through the resistor is small. There is a trade off between discharge time and wasted current. You may not need this resistor if the load current is enough.

**Update:**

Although my answer is accepted, Jasen's solution may work as well as any. Both solutions provide temporary wetting (sealing) current. Once wetted the contacts operate at a reduced current which may not be able to maintain the seal over extended periods. The question was about capacitive wetting at the moment of switching and so was answered that way. My preferred solution would be a limit switch with gold plated contacts.

Comment: Thanks. That's really what i want. Where can I find full original document?

Comment: I calculated. bounce time is normally 5ms. I need too big capacior. I just want to use 0.1uF~0.01uF range. Is it possible to apply that bound condition in real situation? I can meet peak current but it's very hard to meet bounce time. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Is this a solution? I think that
if contacts are oxidated and resistance is so high, C1 0.01uF will be discharged by exsiting load. So, C1 will be ready to charge from the switch.
24V is enough to breakdown the oxidation film and current will flow through the switch with Vc1/R1 peak current during very short period of time. If current is not enough, contact resistance will be higher.
If so, C1 will be also discharged and ready to charge.
voltage across limit switch will be increased and then breakdown ...... [Edited by a moderator to fit, when moved into comments.]

Comment: (continued) I think This mechanism will maintain the contact resistance lower.

Our circuit will be work well, even though       
Contact resistance is 100kohms.

I think wetting current is enough with this circuit.
How do you think?

[wetting current concept schematic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USYul.jpg) ... [Edited by a moderator to fit, when moved into comments.]

Answer (score 4):

you have 100mA and want at-least 160mA

100mA may actually be close enough,

You can get more current with a capacitor but the current is somewhat uncontrolled.

Adding an RC snubber across the contacts can boost the initial current, you should maintain the 160mA until after toe contacts stop bouncing,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMCCNp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

so for the extra 60mA at 24V you want 400 ohms, but the capacitor will discharge a bit so the available voltage will be less.

Which capacitor you chose depends on how long the contacts will bounce for.

Comment: The question states 100uA, not 100mA - so maybe around 120ohms would be more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. I attached the concept drawing. I know the peak current calculation and simulation. But, i don't know how much joule energy(heat) is needed. Peak can make pin hole of oxidation layer. After that we need to supply heat energy to get rid of near pin hole area. Is it enough to supply peak current for very short period of time to avoid oxidation effect?(ex, <1us??) That's my point of calculation that i want to know. Thanks.

Comment: it needs to be long enough that the contacts settlle, look at the contact bounce time in the datasheet, or measure it.

Comment: @RussellH assuming the supply is a DC voltage source (and therfore an AC short circuit)  the RC is across the load. and across the switch contacts... am I missing something?

Comment: @RussellH putting the cap in parallel with the switch is not "shunting the current around the contacts". With the switch open, the cap will charge up through the load. Then when the switch closes, the cap discharges through the switch, so the switch sees the sum of load current + cap discharge current.

Comment: Is this a solution? I think that
if contacts are oxidated and resistance is so high, C1 0.01uF will be discharged by exsiting load. So, C1 will be ready to charge from the switch.
24V is enough to breakdown the oxidation film and current will flow through the switch with Vc1/R1 peak current during very short period of time. If current is not enough, contact resistance will be higher.
If so, C1 will be also discharged and ready to charge.
voltage across limit switch will be increased and then breakdown ...... [Edited by a moderator to fit, when moved into comments.]

Comment: (continued) I think This mechanism will maintain the contact resistance lower.

Our circuit will be work well, even though       
Contact resistance is 100kohms.

I think wetting current is enough with this circuit.
How do you think?

[wetting current concept schematic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USYul.jpg) ... [Edited by a moderator to fit, when moved into comments.]

Comment: Thanks @brhans. Missed that. Makes sense,